# How do I get firebuglite to load opened?

Tags: javascript, console, firebug, firebug-lite

here's the code I have so far:

```
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptTag.src = 'http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
    var ready = function() {console.log('test');};
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (scriptTag.readyState == 'complete') {
            ready();
        }
    }
    scriptTag.onload = ready;
```

The problem is that when I use it, firebug just sits there in the lower right corner. I would like it to actually open up and show the log message.

It's the difference between [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqUkP/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hqUkP/1/)

What is that bookmarklet doing different?

Comment: Is this in chrome or FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqUkP/2/) I just needed to add '#startOpened' to the end of the url